# Name of theorem?

Tags: integration, inequality

I am trying to understand a proof which uses the following statement without further explanation, so I am wondering if this is a well known theorem?

For the unit ball $B$ with radius $r>0$ and the function $f:B\to \mathbb{R}$ with mean value $a$ which is continuous in $\mathcal{L}^2$:

$$\int_{B}{|f-a|} \le cr\int_{B}{|Df|}$$
where $c$ is a constant and $|Df|$ represents the first derivative.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Is the integral over all of $B$? Is $Df$ the derivative?

Comment: Thanks for your comments! I added the information that was missing...

Comment: This is (one of many versions of) the Poincaré inequality. You should be a little careful about the assumptions on your function, since mere continuity doesn't guarantee that $Df$ exists. (Or of course, $Df$ might be zero a.e. without $f$ being constant, as for the Cantor staircase function.)